# Defining the Moyal Product in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, operators

What would be the best way to define the Moyal Product, $f(x,p)\star g(x,p)$, in Mathematica?

$f(x,p)\star g(x,p)$ may be written as $f\star g=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{i\hbar}{2}\right)^n\Pi^n(f,g)$ where $\Pi^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}\frac{\partial^nf}{\partial p^k\partial x^{n-k}}\frac{\partial^ng}{\partial x^k\partial p^{n-k}}$

I'm also wondering how I would then be able to define $f(x,p)\tilde{\star}g(x,p)$ as $f\star(1+\alpha\star_1+\alpha^2\star_2)g$ with $\star_1=cp^3\overleftarrow{\partial_p}\overrightarrow{\partial_p}$, $\star_2=c^2p^6\overleftarrow{\partial^2_p}\overrightarrow{\partial^2_p}$, and c being a constant.

Thanks.

$\Large{\rm{\bf{Edit}}}$

Here's how I tried to define the Moyal product:

```
Star[f_, g_] = 
 Sum[(I*h/2)^n*
   Sum[(-1)^k*Binomial[n, k]*D[f[x, p], {p, k}, {x, n - k}]*
     D[g[x, p], {x, k}, {p, n - k}], {k, 0, n}], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

which output

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } 2^{-n} (i h)^n \sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} f^{(n-k,k)}(x,p) g^{(k,n-k)}(x,p)$

I know that $x\star p=xp+\frac{i\hbar}{2}$, so I tried Star[x,p], but got the following output:

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } 2^{-n} (i h)^n \sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} p^{(k,n-k)}(x,p) x^{(n-k,k)}(x,p)$

I think my problem is where I used f and g in the function of Star, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Once I figure out how to define $f\star g$ in Mathematica, I think I'll be able to define $f\tilde{\star} g$.

$\Large{\rm{\bf{Edit}}}$

I've included the $\frac{1}{n!}$ in the definition of the Moyal Product.

Comment: It seems quite straightforward. What difficulties are you finding?

Comment: You may want to look at the Notation package.

Comment: In hindsight, I should have attached my first attempt at defining the function. I've edited my question.

Comment: Apparently the problem is related to a limit calculation. If you use `star[f_, g_] := 
 Sum[(I*h/2)^n*
   Sum[(-1)^k*Binomial[n, k]*D[f, {p, k}, {x, n - k}]*
     D[g, {x, k}, {p, n - k}], {k, 0, n}], {n, 0, 10}]` it works as expected

Comment: There's also the fact that with your current definition you'd have to call `Star[Function[{x, p}, x], Function[{x, p}, p]]` instead of `Star[x, p]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

The definition of the Moyal product in the original question was missing a factor `1/n!` under the sum. I used the textbook definition instead. A reference for this definition, without any unnecessary technicalities, is here: [Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5269v2) (arXiv), see the appendix. Thanks to Rahul Narain for spotting the discrepancy between my textbook definition and the original form of the question.

In the following, I also set the constant `h` from the question equal to `1`.

**First part of the solution: polynomials**

The best implementation depends on the function space that you're interested in. Based on the examples for `f` and `g` in your question, (`f=x` and `g=p` for example), I am going to assume **first** that the function space consists of the polynomials in the variables `x` and `p`. At the **end**, I'll address how to define the star product for more general functions.

Given two polynomials, we already know that for any two functions the series will reduce to a finite sum. We just have to make sure that we do the sum to a large enough number of terms. Instead of implementing the definition you give in the question, however, I decided to use an equivalent but *different* definition, in which the operators can be ordered so that they are to the left of *both* functions.

The way to do this is simply to write the "dyadic" derivatives appearing in the original question as follows:

$$f(x, p)\frac{\overleftarrow{\partial}}{\partial x}\frac{\overrightarrow{\partial}}{\partial p} g(x,p)= \left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1\partial p} f(x_1, p_1) g(x,p) \right]_{x_1\to x, p_1\to p}
$$

Then the series expansion can be written in terms of the (normal) [operator exponential](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51514/245). In the answer to the lined question, I defined this operator using `Fold`, but this required knowing the expansion order beforehand.

In our case, the assumption of polynomial functions `f` and `g` alone doesn't tell us the maximum number of terms that will be needed. Instead, we should define the operator exponential such that its recursive formula automatically terminates when the sum no longer changes (this cutoff is guaranteed to exist for polynomials).

This is why I implement another version of the `operatorExp` function below, using [`FixedPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FixedPoint.html) to sum up all terms in the usual exponential series until the result no longer changes. The construction is a little uglier than using the linked approach based on `Fold` because I have to keep track of the powers "manually" in a list (containing three elements, the first of which is the partial sum) that is passed on in each recursion step.

Using the first equation, the Moyal product can be written as

$$f\star g=\lim_{x'\to x}\lim_{p'\to p}\sum_{\nu=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\nu!}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^{\nu}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}-\frac{\partial}{\partial p'}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^{\nu}f(x',p')\, g(x,p)$$

which is an exponential:

$$f\star g=\lim_{x'\to x}\lim_{p'\to p}\exp\!\left[\frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}-\frac{\partial}{\partial p'}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\right]\,f(x',p')\, g(x,p)$$

After defining the exponential in such a way that I don't have to evaluate factorials and binomials at every step, I define the exponent (`poissonOp`, in the square brackets above) as an operator acting on the four variables $x_1, p_1, x, p$ introduced above.

Finally, I define the `star` product, but only for polynomials.

```
Clear[operatorExp];
operatorExp[dop_, n_: 100][f_] := First@FixedPoint[
   {#[[1]] + dop[#[[2]]], dop[#[[2]]]/#[[3]], #[[3]] + 1} &, {f, f, 2},
   n, SameTest -> (PossibleZeroQ[#[[1]] - #2[[1]]] &)]

Clear[poissonOp];
poissonOp[x1_, p1_, x_, p_] := 
  Function[f, I/2 (D[f, x1, p] - D[f, p1, x])];

Clear[star];
star[f_?(PolynomialQ[#, {x, p}] &), g_?(PolynomialQ[#, {x, p}] &)] := 
 Module[{x1, p1},
  operatorExp[
     poissonOp[x1, p1, x, p]][(f /. {x :> x1, p :> p1}) g] /. {x1 :> 
     x, p1 :> p}
  ]
```

Here are some tests:

```
star[x, p]

(* ==> I/2 + p x *)

star[x, p] - star[p, x]

(* ==> I *)

star[x, p^2]

(* ==> I p + p^2 x *)

star[x^6 p^2, p^7 x^4]

(*
==> (945 p x^2)/4 - 2205/2 I p^2 x^3 - (2205 p^3 x^4)/4 - 
 2205/2 I p^4 x^5 - 840 p^5 x^6 + 42 I p^6 x^7 - (153 p^7 x^8)/2 + 
 17 I p^8 x^9 + p^9 x^10
*)
```

In principle, this can be applied to arbitrary polynomials. In practice, I put in a "failsafe" to prevent hanging, by adding a third argument to `FixedPoint` in `operatorExp`, specifying the maximum number of terms to which the recursion is pushed. The default value is `n=100`, but it could in principle be made arbitrarily large. Again, this assumes that you know your function space to be polynomials.

If, on the other hand, the functions are not polynomials, then you could still use the Fourier transform approach I also mention in the answer linked above. This will also be made easier by rewriting the left and right acting derivatives as I did here.

**Edit: More general functions**

Elaborating on the Fourier-transform approach, you should also be able to use the following definition (limited only by *Mathematica*'s ability to do the required transforms):

```
star[f_, g_] := FourierTransform[
   InverseFourierTransform[f, {x, p}, {kf, lf}]
    InverseFourierTransform[g, {x, p}, {kg, lg}]
    Exp[I/2 (-kf lg + kg lf)],
   {kf, lf, kg, lg},
   {x1, p1, x, p}
   ] /. {x1 -> x, p1 -> p}
```

This uses the fact that the derivative operators turn into numbers when applied to the Fourier basis functions. Here is an example using Gaussians of different widths:

```
star[Exp[-x^2 - p^2], Exp[-x^2/2 - p^2/2]]

(* ==> 2/3 E^(1/3 (-3 p^2 + (p - I x)^2 - 3 x^2 + (I p + x)^2)) *)
```

The Fourier method **also works** for polynomials, but is slower in that case because it requires some pretty complicated manipulations with Dirac delta functions (which *Mathematica* does correctly, though). For speed reasons, both definitions of `star` can be used side by side. The correct choice of method will be made based on `f` and `g`.

**Edit: brute-force fix for pathological functions**

Here is a version of the Fourier approach that attempts to deal with cases where the required multi-dimensional Fourier transform fails. Since this was motivated by Karan's comment regarding a pathological function with non-compact support, I don't claim that it's the unique and best way to deal with such cases. But one can argue that re-arranging the order of integration variables is a good first try when an integration fails:

```
star[f_, g_] := If[
    Head[#] === FourierTransform,
    # /. {kg, lg, kf, lf} -> {kf, lf, kg, lg}, #] &[
  FourierTransform[
    InverseFourierTransform[
      f, {x, p}, {kf, lf}] InverseFourierTransform[
      g, {x, p}, {kg, lg}] Exp[I/2 (-kf lg + kg lf)], {kg, lg, kf, 
     lf}, {x1, p1, x, p}]] /. {x1 -> x, p1 -> p}
```

An example where this is needed would be a pathological function such as `f = 1/x^2`. In *Mathematica* 8.0.4, there is no problem doing the required Fourier transforms in `star[1/x^2,p]` or `star[p,1/x^2]`, independently of the order, provided you first set `$Assumptions=x>0`. But in versions 9 and 10, you will need the last definition of `star`. What happens is that the `FourierTransform` initially remains unevaluated for `star[p,1/x^2]` (*Mathemtatica* tries for a while but then gives up). In that case, the `If` statement takes the unevaluated result and switches the order of the Fourier integration variables. The justification for this is that it produces a result which differs from the opposite order `star[1/x^2,p]` in the expected way, so it preserves the desired skew symmetry of the Moyal bracket.

Comment: Using the Fourier transform code, I tried to compute star[1/x,p] with Assumptions x>0 and it gives the correct answer but with star[1/x^2,p] I get `FourierTransform[-2 I E^(1/2 I (kg lf - kf lg))
   kf \[Pi]^2 DiracDelta[kg] DiracDelta[lf] Sign[kf] Derivative[1][DiracDelta][lg], {kf, lf, kg, lg}, {x, p, x, p}]` whereas star[p,1/x^2] gives the correct answer. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (what version of MMA are you using?). Setting `$Assumptions={x>0}` before doing the tests, both orders of the `star` work fine and give consistent results, no left-over FT or deltas.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9 and I set `$Assumptions={x>0}` at the beginning of the code as well. I tried quitting the kernel (and restarting MMA) and it still gives me the same results. Strange.

Comment: I get the correct result from `star[(x + a)^-2, p] /. a :> 0`.

Comment: @Karan must be a problem with version 9. In v. 8  this doesn't happen...

Comment: @Karan Indeed, I checked and your observation is a bug in *Mathematica* version 9.0.0 which has been fixed in version 9.0.1.

Comment: Your final test doesn't match the result I get with @belisarius's code in the comments: `9525600 h^8 p x^2 - 5556600 I h^7 p^2 x^3 - 396900 h^6 p^3 x^4 - 132300 I h^5 p^4 x^5 - 20160 h^4 p^5 x^6 + 252 I h^3 p^6 x^7 - 153 h^2 p^7 x^8 + 17 I h p^8 x^9 + p^9 x^10`. The last two terms agree but the others don't. I don't know which result is correct.

Comment: @RahulNarain The code by belisarius was an example, not intended to be the exact result. He only added up the first 10 terms of an infinite sum, in order to show that the problem lies in the limit of infinitely many terms. So you cannot do my last example with the code in the question or in the comment.

Comment: Sorry, by "final test" I meant the final one of your "Here are some tests" block, namely `star[x^6 p^2, p^7 x^4]`. I also should have mentioned that I took the sum up to 100 terms and the result didn't change, so I assumed that it had converged. As you stated, for any two polynomials the series will reduce to a finite sum, and that is what the above result seems to be.

Comment: @RahulNarain Oh, I didn't even notice that the definition of the star product in the question is wrong. The textbook definition is the exponential I wrote down. If you believe my version (which you can find in the literature), then the definition in the question is missing a factor `1/n!` under the sum. Also, I of course set `h=1`. So the discrepancy won't show up unless higher terms `n>1` are involved in the sum. I can add some references, but I haven't heard from the OP at all so I don't know if it's worth it. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I for one am perfectly happy to take your word for it.

Comment: @Jens I reported the problem to Mathematica. However I am still getting the buggy behavior in 9.0.1. It does run fine on 8.0.4 as you mentioned.

Comment: @Karan Yes, I think you're right - I checked again and 9.0.1 isn't working for the `star[1/x^2,p]` case because it can't do the FT. But in any case, that's a very pathological kind of function, so I'm not totally sure it's a real bug. Are you perhaps doing something in polar coordinates? Then the phase space integral has to be done differently, including the proper Jacobian. So the naive star product definition may not be what you need anyway.

Comment: @Jens The MMA support guys replied and confirmed that it is a problem with the Integrate because it generates some ConditionalExpression which doesn't let it integrate. This is actually not polar coordinates but a type of nonlinear realization of noncompact Lie algebras which includes 1/x and 1/x^2 type terms. I am trying to see if the algebra defined by these nonlinear generators that closes under normal Lie bracket will also close under star bracket. Hence I need to use the star product between x and p normalized such that their star bracket is 1. I am not sure if x,p are correct variables.

Comment: @Karan OK - ConditionalExpressions are of course also a warning for you to stop and think about the validity of what you're doing... basically the order of integrations seems to matter, and boundary terms could be cropping up in partial integrations. I think that goes beyond what the question asked for. But I could post a brute-force fix for this issue anyway.

Comment: @Jens I was worried about those issues but the fact that MMA 8 seems to give the right results makes me wonder if these ConditionalExpressions are meaningful. Also I am doing the integration away from the pole i.e. x>0 so x^-n is well defined in which case integrals should give the correct expressions. Is that not correct?

Comment: @Karan I think if what you really want is for the star product to keep its defining properties, then either your limiting approach in the earlier comment or brute-force ignoring of the conditional expression should be permitted. The last update to my answer should also do the trick.

Comment: @Jens Thanks a lot for the fix. It helps a lot!

Comment: @Jens Thanks for pointing out the missing factorial in the Moyal Product. For some reason, I didn't see it, even after proofreading my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

```
star[f_, g_] := 
 Sum[(I \[HBar]/2)^n 1/
    n! Nest[ D[#, p, x1] - D[#, x, p1] &, (f /. {x -> x1, p -> p1})*g,
      n], {n, 0, Plus @@ Exponent[f, {x, p}]}] /. {x1 -> x, p1 -> p}

 AbsoluteTiming @ star[x^6 p^2, p^7 x^4] 

 {0.00201501, 
 p^9 x^10 + 17 I p^8 x^9 \[HBar] - 153/2 p^7 x^8 \[HBar]^2 + 
 42 I p^6 x^7 \[HBar]^3 - 840 p^5 x^6 \[HBar]^4 - 
 2205/2 I p^4 x^5 \[HBar]^5 - 2205/4 p^3 x^4 \[HBar]^6 - 
 2205/2 I p^2 x^3 \[HBar]^7 + 945/4 p x^2 \[HBar]^8}
```

Comment: Hi F. Kampas, welcome to SE! Do you think you could include an example of your code? Thanks!

Comment: AbsoluteTiming @ star[x^6 p^2, p^7 x^4] {0.00201501, p^9 x^10 + 17 I p^8 x^9 \[HBar] - 153/2 p^7 x^8 \[HBar]^2 + 42 I p^6 x^7 \[HBar]^3 - 840 p^5 x^6 \[HBar]^4 - 2205/2 I p^4 x^5 \[HBar]^5 - 2205/4 p^3 x^4 \[HBar]^6 - 2205/2 I p^2 x^3 \[HBar]^7 + 945/4 p x^2 \[HBar]^8}